# Not able to install EMM certificate in Apple Device

Tags: ipad, wso2, mdm, wso2-iot

I want to download the EMM agent on my Ipad but when i start the enrollment process of the agent it goes to install EMM certificate.When i click to install it gives an error (Cannot Install Profile-Safari could not install a profile due to an unknown error).Also i am not able to directly download the agent app ,it is giving an error "Could not connect to ". Any suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: Could you please check whether your profile is expired? "Cannot Install Profile-Safari could not install a profile due to an unknown error" could be due to expired certificate. Reason for the "Could not connect to <ip/host>" is, you should have install the certificate before you download the agent.

Comment: The certificate itself is not getting downloaded.Its showing error "Could not connect to <ip>"

Comment: Do you have your device and the server in same network? This should be due to a configuration issue. ould you please verify your configurations from https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM200/iOS+Server+Configurations?

Comment: Also check the http_access logs at <EMM_HOME>/repository/logs location when you click download certificate option

Comment: I am still not able to resolve the issue of "Cannot Install Profile-Safari could not install a profile due to an unknown error",while installing the certificate.